# is Robot (Swing FEST) a singleton class?

Tags: java, swing, fest

Recently I experienced that is a Robot instance is created already and if try to create it again (obviously without calling robot.cleanUp()) it hangs there forever. I investigated this and got to know that it takes a ScreenLock every time we create a Robot instance.

So my question is this kind of behaviour can be achieved by Singleton class. Then why we are allowed to create another Robot instance although it is a deadlock situation. I mean if I am to Create Robot, clean it up and create again then why should I clean and recreate it in the first place? There should be one API which will provide Robot instance upon user request because current approach does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

But, there is a constructor new Robot(GraphicsDevice screen), which creates a Robot instance with coordinate system relative to this screen. For this purpose it make sense to have multiple instances of Robot.